# How do I force Maven to use maven-install-plugin version 2.5?

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I want to install few jars to my local maven repo with maven-install-plugin. My maven 3.2.1 installation uses version 2.4 of this plugin which requires a lot of parameters to specify. I would like to use version 2.5 that requires less parameters, as mentioned on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html. If I run    `mvn install:install-file` from the folder that has a pom.xml file with the following, then it uses version 2.5:

```
<pluginManagement>
 <plugins>
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Otherwise, it still uses the old plugin. How do I force Maven to use maven-install-plugin version 2.5 (if I run install-file from any folder)?

P.S. [How to install third party source and javadoc JARs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633664/how-to-install-third-party-source-and-javadoc-jars) does not contain the answer.

Comment: Can you provide us your full pom?

Comment: I've added to my post more xml nodes from the pom. The other pom settings are generic.

Comment: Use version in the command `mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal`.

Comment: You have to specify the plugin not in `<pluginManagement>` tag. Instead it should be in your `<build>` tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM Could you give more specific example?

Comment: @Zarathustra Actually, my question is how to set the version of the plugin globally, not in one of the build files.

Comment: Run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5:install-file`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install third party source and javadoc JARs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633664/how-to-install-third-party-source-and-javadoc-jars)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answered in comments:

> Run mvn
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5:install-file. – 
>   Aleksandr M Aug 8 '14 at 8:47

Clarification:

Aleksandr M means that this is possible using the [`install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal of the maven-install-plugin. This requires you to specify the file to be installed using the `-file` flag. This is explained in more detail in the maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to declare `maven-install-plugin` with 2.5.x version inside project's `pom.xml` -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```